# ¿Cuándo borras los datos de una aplicación, se borran las alarmas programadas por esta?

Tags: android

Usando `AlarmManager`, para crear Alarmas, me surge esta duda, ya que estoy intentando programar una aplicación que dispara una alarma a intervalos para comunicarse con un servidor y modificar la base de datos de la app en consecuencia.

> Si se borran los datos de la app, ¿la alarma seguirá ejecutándose
>   indefinidamente?

Comment: a que te refieres con una alarma? Intenta explicarte un poco mejor para que podamos echarte una mano [ask]

Comment: Sí, debí especificar que las alarmas a las que me refería son de las que programas con la clase AlarmManager de Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Si se borran los datos de la app, ¿la alarma seguirá ejecutándose
>   indefinidamente?

Los datos son independientes del registro de las alarmas, a menos que tu aplicación determine su ejecución, inicio, terminación de las alarmas en base a datos almacenados en el dispositivo (SharedPreferences, base de datos, archivo, etc).

**En cambio si la aplicación que creo las alarmas es desinstalada**, no habrá nada para manejar los PendingIntent de las alarmas. 
Los PendingIntent podrìan ser transmitidos, pero nadie los manejará y el sistema realizará su eliminación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Un placer, saludos!.